# SlickGrid overlay issue in Jquery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, slickgrid

There seems to be an overlay issue when slickgrid is inside a jquery ui tab. I am not sure how to fix it.

To reproduce the isse, Please try this [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DENmT/)

Please scroll the grid in Tab1 and switch to Tab2. When we switch back to Tab 1. The grid is empty. This seems to happen in chrome and IE, not an issue in firefox !

Filed an issue [here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/211):

Please let me know if I'm missing something.

**Solution:** Solved it with the hint from an [earlier post](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/88). Used the off-left technique to hide inactive tabs.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the hint from an [earlier post](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/88). Used the off-left technique to hide inactive tabs.